# Open a browser tab from chrome-app, with access to localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to open a regular browser tab from within my chrome app.
I want the tab opened, no need to communicate between them.
So far I have tried the following two methods which both create and load the new tab.

```
var a =  document.createElement('a')
a.href = "https://example.com";
a.target = "_blank";
a.click();

var w = window.open(s.Url, "_blank");
w.focus();
```

One more attempt that result in the same. This one is hardcoded into the html and activated by the user clicking on it. So the problem is not related to javascript itself but the way chrome handles external links.

```
<a href="https://example.com/" target="_blank">Open external website</a>
```

However in these created tabs localStorage is null.
Apparently the tab is still open in some app environment.
If I copy the URL and paste it inside a new tab localStorage is available.

How can I open a new browser tab similar to the user copy/pasting the url.

*UPDATE* The app was started using window.open from the background page to create a tab rather than a new window. If chrome.app.window.create was used, the links opened correctly in the browser with localStorage available.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the symptoms, you are doing this from the background (events) page. window.open() is currently very buggy when called from the background page. There is a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=252464) filed for that and a [proposal](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1WL7MVJLhVLujkEfoS7S0qrgbtVy05rJ4Psv9Pp6VDzc/edit?usp=sharing) for an API aimed to fix that. Here's what you can do in the meantime:

1. In your solution with document.createElement('a'), you are creating your element in a wrong document ("wrong" in light of the bug above). That's the document of the background page's window, and you should be using the one of the content window. Change the way you're creating the element to:

   `var a = win.contentWindow.document.createElement('a');`

   where `win` is the app window object returned in the callback of    `chrome.app.window.create`. This should work.
2. You can't do anything to fix window.open() in the background page, but see #3 below.
3. Alternatively, if it's possible in your case, you can move any of your 2 solutions unchanged to a script invoked from your .html:

**main.html**

```
<html>
  <body>
    ...
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```
function SomeEventHandler() {
  // This...
  var a = document.createElement('a')
  a.href = "https://example.com";
  a.target = "_blank";
  a.click();

  // ... or this will both work.
  window.open("https://example.com");
}
```

Comment: It's not a background page but a visible chrome-app tab, which is in some way isolated. The previous code examples was not run in a chrome.app.window but in a tab created using window.open from the background page.